# Replace VSC Editor Compiler Path Defaults

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I erased VSC and installed it again, and the C++ editor got weird.

I'd like to change the compiler that the C++ editor uses to find errors in code in real time and display automatic completion to g++-12. (It was supposed to be like that.) What should I do?

(Temporary c_cpp_properties.json changes the compiler path to g++-12 every time, but it's too much trouble because there are many directories...)

Comment: the used compiler is defined in the task, have you read the VSC C++ doc pages

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't find the answer I was looking for.

Comment: I solved the problem. When I put g++-12 in "C_Cpp › Default: Compile Commands", parsing failed, so, even the default value of "C_Cpp › Default: CompilerPath" was not included.

Comment: If you think the answer can help other people, write up an answer following [answer]. Otherwise, consider deleting this question.

Answer (score 0):

When I put g++-12 in "C_Cpp › Default: Compile Commands", parsing failed, so, even the default value of "C_Cpp › Default: CompilerPath" was not included.

Comment: Edit your post and add the additional information to it, not adding additional information is answer section.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33811033)